# Reducing the vertical line height in an array environment

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, arrays, arydshln

When I try to use

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\begin{document}
\[\left[
    \begin{array}{c:c:c}
        \begin{bmatrix}A_l& A_{nl}\end{bmatrix} & B_r & \begin{bmatrix}B_l& B_{nl}\end{bmatrix} \\
        \hdashline
        C &0&0
    \end{array}
    \right]\]
\end{document}
```

I get:

[image]

In this, how can I ensure that the dotted vertical lines stay within the top and bottom bounds defined by the left-right brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `bigstrut` to slightly increase the brackets size. Icing on the cake: the horizontal  dash line has some vertical padding.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\[ \left[
    \begin{array}{c:c:c}
        \begin{bmatrix}A_l& A_{nl}\end{bmatrix} & B_r & \begin{bmatrix}B_l& B_{nl}\end{bmatrix} \bigstrut\\
        \hdashline
        C &0&0 \bigstrut[t]
    \end{array}
    \right] \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly! Also, if possible, could you briefly explain the usage of `bigstut[.]`? This is, atleast to me, a completely a new package.

Comment: I think this answers my previous question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446772/introducing-a-point-space-in-equations-with-a-matrix-within-an-array) :D here the vertical dashed lines are still going out of the bracket heights:

Comment: It's a package which comes with `multirow`. Fundamentally it adds a fixed height and depth to a row cell. This added length is `\bigstrutjot` which defaults to 2pt. You also can use an optional argument: `[t]` (acts on the height only) or `[b]` (acts on the depth).

Comment: Understood in a basic level.

Comment: The dashes are still going out of the inner brackets, not the outer brackets. If you think the difference with the outer brackets is not enough, you can set `\bigstrutjot` to, say, 3pt.

Comment: Ok clear, then this answered both of my questions.